# Problem with a join query rendered to xml - Rails 3

Tags: xml, ruby-on-rails-3, join

please can you explain me why this code

```
@activities = Activity.joins(:events, :infos).where("infos.language_id = ? and events.home = ?", params[:language_id], true)
respond_to do |format|
  format.xml  { render :xml => @activities.to_xml(:include => [:infos, :events]) }
end
```

is returning me an XML with the infos in every language (and not only the specified one), and with every event linked to the activity (and not only the events with `:home => true`).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i still don't understand why the above doesn't work, but i found the solution:

```
@activities = Activity.all(:include => [:infos, :events], :conditions => ["infos.language_id = ? and events.home = ?", params[:language_id], true] )
respond_to do |format|
  format.xml  { render :xml => @activities.to_xml(:include => [:infos, :events]) }
end
```